# Download Google App email not using POP or IMAP

Tags: gmail, google-apps-email, export

I just recently graduated from a college and want to download my emails.  The college uses Google apps however they do not allow IMAP or POP.  I have emailed the school about this but they are not helpful at all.

I was wondering if there was a way to download emails using either some API or perhaps some un-mentioned export function that is not widely known.  I have searched for tools that might automatically do this but they all require IMAP or POP which is my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are up to the challenge you could try forwarding each and every message to a new email address, but this would require some tricky filtering as well as header rewriting on the backend.

Here's what I would suggest:

1. Create a filter in Gmail. In the `Has these words:` textbox type "is:read". The action should be to forward to your new email address (which must first be verified). You'll notice Gmail warns you that searches with `is:`, `label:`, or other related operatores are not applied to incoming mail, but you will be fine. You might want to create the corresponding search for new email **first** where you could wildcard the To/From.
2. At this point you would have all your emails forwarded one by one to the new email address, along with future incoming email also forwarded. The tough part is that its a forward and **not** a mail redirect which would be much nicer, keeping headers intact, etc. At this point you'd have to use some text processing or third party programs to perhaps attempt to get rid of the Forward fluff and potentially rewrite headers if it interested you.

Comment: This is the best option.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

From [Google Takeout - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Takeout)

> On December 5, 2013, Google Takeout was further expanded to include
> Gmail and Google Calendar data.

## Explanation

Formerly named [Google Takeout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Takeout), "Google Download your data" offer Gmail messages in [MBOX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox) format.

From [Download your data - Accounts Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190?hl=en)

> You can download the data associated with your Google Account so that
> you can use it in another service or keep a copy for your records.
>
> You can request this info using the “Download your Data” tool. Here’s
> how:
>
> ## Start your download
>
> 1. Sign in to [My Account](https://myaccount.google.com/).
> 2. In the "Personal Info & Privacy" section, select Control your content.
> 3. In the "Download your Data" box, select Create Archive.
> 4. Select the Google products you’d like to include in your download and select Next.
> 5. Choose the file type that you’d like your data in and how you want to get it (either by a download link or directly into your Google
>    Drive).
> 6. Select Create archive.
>
> Once the archive is created, you’ll get an email to let you know it’s
> ready. Depending on the amount of information in your account, this
> process could take a few minutes or several hours, but most people get
> their link the same day they request it.